# why (map (fn [f] (f 0)) `(inc)) returns (nil) in Clojure

Tags: clojure

```clj
uesr=> (defn ff [f] (f 0))
uesr=> (ff inc)
1
uesr=> (map ff `(inc))
(nil)
```

why **ff** could not do well in **map**？

Comment: maybe you knew already but considering the use case i think you want, i.e. running several functions on the same argument can be achieved with the `juxt` higher order function: ```((juxt inc dec (fn [x] (* 2 x))) 1) => [2 0 2]```. It takes a list of functions and returns a single function that returns, as vector, the result of calling each function with the given arg

Answer (score 5):

Look what is passed into `map`:

```
(map #(println %1) '(inc))
inc
=> (nil)

(map #(println %1) `(inc))
clojure.core/inc
=> (nil)
```

Both `inc` are inside quotes, so they don't evaluate to function. In second example, [syntax quote](https://clojure.org/reference/reader#syntax-quote) is used, so `inc` resolves to fully-qualified symbol.

Now your code:

```
(defn ff [f] (f 0))

(map ff `(inc))
=> nil
```

Your function evaluates to:

```
('inc 0)
=> nil

('clojure.core/inc 0)
=> nil
```

Symbols look themselves up in objects:

```
('inc {'inc 1 'dec 2})
=> 1
('inc #{'inc 'dec})
=> inc
```

`'inc` was not found in `0`, so `nil` is returned (you can even add *not-found* argument).

```
('inc 0)
=> nil

('inc 0 1)
=> 1
```

To get result that you want, use `list` or vector:

```
(map #(println %1) [inc])
#object[clojure.core$inc 0x4fa1f07 clojure.core$inc@4fa1f07]
=> (nil)

(map #(%1 0) (list inc))
=> (1)

(map #(%1 0) [inc])
=> (1)
```

Answer (score 3):

The problem is the subexpression

```
`(inc)
```

It evaluates to a list with the single symbol `inc`:

```
`(inc)
;; => (clojure.core/inc)
```

because the backquote *prevents evaluation* of the expression after the quote. This is more obvious if you do

```
(map class `(inc))
;; => (clojure.lang.Symbol)

(every? fn? `(inc))
;; => false
```

If you instead use a *vector literal* or the `list` function to construct a sequence containing the `inc` function as its single element, you will see that it will evaluate to a function:

```
(map class [inc])
;; => (clojure.core$inc)

(every? fn? [inc])
;; => true

(map class (list inc))
;; => (clojure.core$inc)

(every? fn? (list inc))
;; => true
```

The following code will accomplish what you want:

```
(map ff [inc])
;; => (1)
```

Answer (score 1):

Like the previous answerers already answered - just paraphrasing:

`quote`/`'` or `backquote`/``` for constructing a list is NOT identical with `list` for constructing a list, because `list` evaluates each of its elements while constructing the list - while `quote` or `backquote` do not. They generate a list of preliminarily unevaluated symbols.

So `'(inc)` generates a list containing the symbol `inc`, while `(list inc)` generates a list containing the function behind the symbol `inc` - the actual `inc` function.

Answer (score 0):

The trick is that you want inc to be resolved to a var (which is bound to a function that increments).

The resolution happens naturally if you avoid quoting, e.g., by using a vector literal or the `list` function:

```
(map (fn [f] (f 0)) [inc])
(1)

(map (fn [f] (f 0)) (list inc))
(1)
```

But your question is about a literal list.  Quoting inhibits the var resolution.  Therefore, you were on the right track by using the syntax quote (as opposed to the ordinary quote, the apostrophe), because you can unquote s-expressions within a syntax quote:

```
(map (fn [f] (f 0)) `(~inc))
(1)
```